# BLDC motor design, physical appearance question

Tags: design, brushless-dc-motor

Excuse me if this is a dumb question, but I always wondered why are BLDC motors usually quite short in comparison to their diameter? Is it due to some electrical properties that make this design the most effiecient? How would you compare two motors that both take up the same volume but the first one is short and has a large diameter and the other one is long and has a small diameter (if it's even possible).

Comment: There are two common configurations to construct BLDC motors, "outrunner" and "inrunner" type. The outrunner is usually as you describe, relatively short against its diameter. The inrunner type is usually very similar to normal brushed motors in shape, so it's definitely possible to construct motors this way.

Comment: On your question, motors typically come with specifications (torque, max RPM, Kv, efficiency, etc.), so comparing two motors is easy. I don't think shape has much to do with performance. Cost, yes, but not performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the application. 
Servomotors are generally longer than wider and this is in order to keep moment of inertia as low as possible, which increases linearly with the length of motor and with a square of radius. This is where you need dynamics.

For other applications, where top-notch dynamics isn't required it is preferred to increase diameter, since output power (and torque) increases with the diameter squared. With larger diameter the slots are bigger, therefore electric loading can be increased by the number of turns or number of parallel branches to decrease losses/increase current. The length also increases power but linearly as well as power losses both in copper and core.

In series production, it is favorable to pick a basis (given diameter) and increase length in order to achieve higher power and torque ratings. There is also an upper limit to how big the radius can be, given that centrifugal force increases with radius of rotor and with square of speed, so your magnets won't fly off and damage the motor.

Comment: Great! That's a superb answer, thank you and everyone who shared their knowledge. Have a happy new year!